# Why does the hashCode() of an ArrayList change every time you add a new element?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashcode

As per my understanding of `ArrayList`, the default capacity is 10 and when it grows beyond 10, it will create a new object with new capacity and so on..

So out of curiosity, I typed following program to check `hashcode()` for `ArrayList` object:

```
public class TestCoreJava {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

        for(int i=0;i<15;i++){

            al.add("Temp"+i);
            System.out.println("Hashcode for "+i+" element "+al.hashCode());
        }
    }
}
```

According to above scenario, when I am not setting Initial capacity for `ArrayList` the default would be 10. 
So while adding 11th element, it will create a new object and increase the capacity for `ArrayList`.

When I print the hashcode for `ArrayList` object, it is giving a new `hashcode()` each time.

Following is the o/p:

```
Hashcode for 0 element 80692955
Hashcode for 1 element -1712792766
Hashcode for 2 element -1476275268
Hashcode for 3 element 1560799875
Hashcode for 4 element 1220848797
Hashcode for 5 element -727700028
Hashcode for 6 element -1003171458
Hashcode for 7 element -952851195
Hashcode for 8 element 607076959
Hashcode for 9 element 1720209478
Hashcode for 10 element -6600307
Hashcode for 11 element -1998096089
Hashcode for 12 element 690044110
Hashcode for 13 element -1876955640
Hashcode for 14 element 150430735
```

According to the concept of default capacity, till 10th element it should have printed same `hashcode()` as no new object needs to be created until that point, but it is not the case.

Comment: `hashCode()` is tied to `equals()` which indicates that 2 lists with different elements but the same capacity should return different hash codes (which they do if you look at the sources)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The `hashCode` of `ArrayList` is a function of the `hashCode`s of all the elements stored in the `ArrayList`, so it doesn't change when the capacity changes, it changes whenever you add or remove an element or mutate one of the elements in a way that changes its hashCode.

Here's the Java 8 implementation (it's actually implemented in `AbstractList`) :

```
public int hashCode() {
    int hashCode = 1;
    for (E e : this)
        hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
    return hashCode;
}
```

BTW, this is the exact code that appears in the Javadoc of `hashCode()` of the `List` interface :

> **int java.util.List.hashCode()**
>
> Returns the hash code value for this list. The hash code of a list is defined to be the result of the following calculation:

```
int hashCode = 1;
for (E e : list)
    hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
```

Comment: this can give hash collision.  For example if  1+3 = 2+2 that means 2 lists may have same hash .

Comment: @JavaMain Yes, and that isn't a problem. Indeed, in Java, the method `.hashCode()` should give the same hash code for two Object that are equals for `.equals()`, but for two Objects that are different, it does not have to give different hash codes, even though it is better.

Answer (score 6):

The `hashCode` of `List` implementations is [defined in terms of the `hashCode` of its elements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode--). This means that for `ArrayList` to be a conforming `List` implementation it's `hashCode` **must** change when its content changes.

More generally: for mutable objects, the `hashCode` should change whenever they change in a way that would make them not `equal` to their previous state.

You seem to be assuming that it uses the [default `hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) of `Object`, which is not the case.

Additionally, even if `ArrayList` did not implement `hashCode`, the default hash code (also known as the [identity hash code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object))) of an `ArrayList` would not change if the internal array was re-allocated, as the `ArrayList` object itself stays the same, just the internal array object (that you don't get direct access to) will be replaced with a new one.