# How to get a unique hashCode for an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, hash, hashcode

```
var arr1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
var arr2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

System.out.println(arr1.hashCode());
System.out.println(arr2.hashCode());
System.out.println(arr1.equals(arr2));
```

Output:

```
1
1
true
```

After searching, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35702670/9140652) which explains why this is happening.

From the answer:

> Here's the Java 8 implementation (it's actually implemented in
>   `AbstractList`) :
>
> ```
> public int hashCode() {
>     int hashCode = 1;
>     for (E e : this)
>         hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
>     return hashCode;
> }
> ```

And since the two arrays are empty, it's obvious that the `hashCode` function would return `1` for both of the arrays.

My question is, given two `ArrayLists`, how to determine whether they are the same or not? How can I be sure that modifing one `ArrayList` won't affect the other? since I have no unique hash for each `ArrayList`, I can't compare their hashes to know whether they're equal or not. How to get a unique hash for each object?

Also why the `equals` function returns `true`? Does it compare objects by hashes? Are they actually the same object? If yes then why and how to make different objects then?

And what are the classes other than `ArrayList` that acts in this way?

Comment: Just compare the references: `arr1 == arr2` --- As for `equals()`, it returns true because the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) says it has to. Same as the javadoc of [`hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode--) says the two lists must return the same value. Which you would know if you **read the documentation**.

Comment: Hashcodes aren't unique and aren't used to determine equality.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks that works. But how to get a uniuqe number or a string for an object then?

Comment: @user207421 Is there some unique value that I can use? since I can't get the address in memory, is there anything other that the address that I can get?

Comment: `==` compares the reference values. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @user207421 Well, yes that's what I was asking for. But I'm just curious, is there any unique value for each object? that I can get? Maybe the current address in memory or something.

Comment: There is `System.identityHashcode()`.